# Why console.log() is logging 4 times and it's different?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```js
export default function course() {
  const router = useRouter()
  slu= router.asPath.split("/")[2]
  console.log(slu)
  return (<design goes here>);
}
```

So the problem here is that when I use this method it gives me this output
[image]

What I want is the value `1731547675` but instead of that it's giving me `[slug]`
What's wrong that I am doing here

Comment: What is this `setslu(slu)= router.asPath.split("/")[2]`? Please show the real code, because this throws an error

Comment: ah sorry for that it was mistake

Comment: Components in react rerender every time state changes hence that many console logs

Comment: Sounds like strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

It Prints multiple times because the ui is refreshed everytime You set a state
Wrap Your Console.log into a **useEffect** block

```js
const [slu, setslu] = useState(0);
useEffect(()=>
  setslu(router.asPath.split("/")[2])
}
```

Hopefully this helps. Note: Use **const** instead of **let** in creating a state